# How to join an extra table to a belongsToMany collection (In Laravel Eloquent)

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have 3 tables.

**user** - user_id, user_name

**follow_album** -  album_id, follower_user_id

**album** - album_id, album_creator_user_id

```
User Model public function followingAlbum()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('album','follow_album');
}

$user = user::find(1)->first();

$followingAlbum = $user->followingAlbum;
```

So now I have all of the albums that this person is following, the issue is that the collection only contains the album_creator_user_id... and I need to link it back to the user table to get the user_name of the owner. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I wonder that your code actually works. Your keys in your intermediate table don't follow commmon conventions, so you should pass them as parameters to the relation.

```
public function followingAlbums()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Album','follow_album', 'follower_user_id', 'album_id');
}
```

Remember, if your model is named `Album`, it looks for a table named `albums`. If your table is named `album`, you need to set that property in your `Album` model.

```
class Album extends Eloquent {
  protected $table = "album";
  //...
```

Then, you don't need to call `->first()` if you have used `->find(1)`, since find will always return only one result.

If you need the user who created an album, you need to add that relation to your Album model as well.

```
class Album extends Eloquent {
   public class creator() {
     return $this->belongsTo('User', 'album_creator_user_id');
   }
```

That way you can access the creator of an album via the album.
In your case from above, you can get all the albums a user is following like you did

```
$user = User::find(1);
$followingAlbums = $user->followingAlbums;
```

See the plural form - there can be many albums a user is following. In the following example you get only the first album and the creator of that album.

```
$user = User::find(1); //retrieve User with id == 1
$followingAlbum = $user->followingAlbums()->first(); //get the first album he follows
$creator = $followingAlbum->creator; //the user who created the album
```

Comment: Thank you Mattias. I almost had it but you helped me solve the problem. Champion! :)

Comment: One more question - any idea how I can eager load the creator information?

Comment: The information of the creator is available via the object. e.g. if you have an attribute for name, you can access it via $creator->name. Or $followingAlbum->creator->name (gives the name of the user who created followingAlbum)

Comment: If you want to eager load the creator information when looking for albums you can do it like this: $album = Album::with('creator')->first(); $album->creator->name will then not require an additional query